# User not authorized to perform this action when calling a cronjob

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have deployed a cronjob and deployed its cron schedule on Appengine.
However when I am calling the API from postman
`{{appEngineHost}}/publish/delete-users`

I am getting the following response

```
{
    "message": {
        "code": 7,
        "metadata": {
            "_internal_repr": {},
            "flags": 0
        },
        "details": "User not authorized to perform this action.",
        "note": "Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient"
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea on what is the cause of the problem and how to solve it? Thanks

---

**Update:**
I have noticed that the `appspot.gserviceaccount.com` doesn't have the necessary permissions to call the API. I will grant it the needed permissions and will try again

Comment: Refer to this [Github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/536) and [Doc1](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/troubleshooting), [Doc2](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control) which may help in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that there was no permission for the service account to call the cronjobs, I granted it the Editor permission and everything worked fine afterward